# Debugging a prebuilt shared library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to use a C++ shared library, which builds separately and only the binary is copied to my Android project.
Everything is properly working except debugging.
Android Studio's lldb debugger just skips the line of the shared library API call.
The binary is built with all the symbols that are needed.

Would you please give me some idea what I could possibly try?
Thanks.

---

Following is my Android Studio settings, build.gradle and cmake.
[image]

build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ''
            arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
        }
    }
    ndk {
        abiFilters "x86"
        //abiFilters "x86_64"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
        renderscriptDebuggable true
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    doNotStrip "/x86/*.so"
    //doNotStrip "/x86_64/*.so"
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path file('CMakeLists.txt')
        version '3.10.2'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['/src/main/libnode/bin']
    }
}
```

cmake

```
add_library(libnode SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
    libnode
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/libnode/bin/${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI}/libnode.so)

add_library(
    native-lib
    SHARED
    src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
    native-lib
    libnode
    ${log-lib})
```

Answer (score 3):

- The shared library needs to be built with a build id that Android Studio understands, add this to your link options:

`"-Wl,--build-id=sha1"`

(sorry it has been a while since I edited CMake).
More info on the build id can be found in the [NDK build maintainers' guide](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/refs/heads/ndk-release-r22/docs/BuildSystemMaintainers.md)

- The source to the library needs to be indexed by Android Studio, a symbolic link to the source within the source root should be sufficient. For example in `/src/main/cpp/myLib`
- LLDB mapping between the source built into the library and the source on your disk is needed. That is, if the library was built on some other machine and the symbols are unique to that machine, you will need to "map" the symbols so LLDB can find the source on your machine.

  - Find the objdump for your shared library's build-triplet in your NDK, mine is in `toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-objdump` (in this example it is aarch64-linux-android, for an arm64 library), run objdump on the library:

`aarch64-linux-android-objdump -C -l -d myLib.so | grep \\.cpp`

this will print out the paths in the debug symbols when/where it was built.

- If the library was built on a machine in the folder /a/b/c, such that all the relevant symbols in the shared library are of the form `/a/b/c/myLib/src/myFile.cpp`, and the same file is on your machine in `/Studio/x/y/z/src/main/cpp/myLib/src/myFile.cpp` you need to create an LLDB mapping from `/a/b/c` to `/Studio/x/y/z/src/main/cpp`

  - Go into Run > Edit Configurations
  - Set the debugger to hybrid (or native only)
  - set the following command:
    `settings append target.source-map /a/b/c /Studio/x/y/z/src/main/cpp`

If you are using windows, just provide the paths as windows paths, even if the library was built in cygwin or bash, copy the path exactly as objdump provides it.

Comment: Can you specify that source link - e.g. "/src/main/cpp/myLib" - in `build.gradle` or does it have to be set from some menu in Android Studio?

Comment: Android Studio will find the source if the source code has CMakeLists.txt or Android.mk in the `myLib` folder. Presumably the source was built for android into the binary you'd like to debug and should have one of these files.

Comment: this answer indirectly helped me, btw, for me it wasn't necessary to index source files in AS, it was sufficient to open the files from their original location and just put the breakpoint!